# Erro 502.4 configuring load balancer with IIS server Farm

Tags: load-balancing, iis-8.5, arr, asp-classic

I'm trying to do the follow configuration with IIS

SERVER02 - Run two sites (SITE_A with anonymous Authentication, SITE B with WIndows Authentication)
SERVER03 - Run two sites (SITE_A with anonymous Authentication, SITE B with WIndows Authentication)

SERVER01 - Running IIS with ARR and two server Farms.

Server Farm Site A - point to SITE A in SERVER02 and SERVER03
Server Farm Site B - point to SITE B in SERVER02 and SERVER03

If I access site A or B directly to server01 or server02, everthing works well, so the problem is in SERVER03.

Accessing SITE A or B in server03 I receive erro code 502.4

In SITE B and A I see error 502.4  on server03 and 302 on the others servers.

Someone can tll what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My server farm was configured with a different name than the server-url.